# Prevent page break after \midrule in \longtable

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, rules

I'm trying to tell `longtable` to only issue a page break at one specific point (by using `\\*`. Putting a `\midrule` anywhere near that point causes a page break after the midrule, and not where I want it to be.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c}
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\*
Last line on this page \\
bla \\*%\midrule
bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

It produces the correct result:

> [image]

My problem comes up after uncommenting the `\midrule`:

> [image]

I tried preventing the page break after the `\midrule` by inserting `\nopagebreak` before and/or after it, but to no avail.

P.S.: I know that right fter a rule would usually be a desired point for a page break in a table. However, I am using rules before and after certain lines to create some kind of seperator between blocks of rows. Thus, the rule must stay on top of the following line and the page brak should occur right after the last `\\*` *before* the rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not confined to booktabs: Also with a standard `\hline` you would get a break. longtable redefines `\hline` so that it actually inserts two lines with a break point between them. This way a line at the bottom of a page is repeated on the top of the next page. You could define you a command which changes the penalty used by the `\hline` and the width temporarly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\makeatletter

\newlength\oriarrayrulewidth  
\newcount\orilowpenalty
\newcommand\nobreakmidrule{%
 \noalign{\global\oriarrayrulewidth\arrayrulewidth\relax
          \global\orilowpenalty\@lowpenalty\relax  
          \global\@lowpenalty=\numexpr-10000\relax%
          \global\arrayrulewidth\lightrulewidth\relax}
 \hline
 \noalign{\global\@lowpenalty=\orilowpenalty\relax%
          \global\arrayrulewidth\oriarrayrulewidth\relax}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c}
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\*
Last line on this page \\
bla \\*\nobreakmidrule
bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have the same problem and this looks interesting, but why are the redefinitions `\global`? I worry about introducing regressions elsewhere in my document.

Comment: +1: Thanks. Looks like a bug in longtable to me then? Do you agree? If yes, I would try to create a bug report.

Answer (score 7):

easiest is to force a break where you want a break

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c}
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
bla \\*
Last line on this page \\
bla \\\pagebreak\midrule
bla \\*
bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\* bla \\*
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty obvious, but I didn't think of it. :) This will do for now.