# How to define potential page breaks in a long table?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, tabularx, ltablex

I have a huge table that covers multiple pages:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%Column width for tables
\def \firstColumnWidth {3.5cm}
\def \secondColumnWidth {12.5cm}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{\firstColumnWidth}p{\secondColumnWidth}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2015}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2014}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2013}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

In this example, the page break is directly after the 2013 column. However, I want to have the page break either bevor the 2013 column, or after the Foo column. Is there any way to specify in a table where potential page breaks can be. I don't want to add page breaks manually, since the content is dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\\*` to prevent a page break

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2013}\\*
```

If lines are involved you need to change the commands for the lines too:

[Prevent page break after \midrule in \longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186620/prevent-page-break-after-midrule-in-longtable/186702#186702)

[How to disable pagebreak on \hline in longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/how-to-disable-pagebreak-on-hline-in-longtable)