# Longtable: Doesn't respect respect \nopagebreak in conjunction with \hline or \cline. Fix?

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I have some rows separated by \cline's. It's important for presentation that they appear on the same page. However the \nopagebreak doesn't work in conjunction with \hline or \cline. Is there any easy fix for this?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/how-to-disable-pagebreak-on-hline-in-longtable and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186702/2388

Comment: it respects `\nopagebreak` in that it doesn't break where the `\nopagebreak` is, it's just that it breaks inside the `\hline` anyway. Not that that helps you it just means my documentation isn't wrong:-) The links Ulrike gave should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a corresponding fix for \cline?